# Can't create .xlsx file

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to create '.xlxs' file via *xlsxwriter* but it doesn't create.
After entering the command, nothing happens.

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('file.xlsx')
```

Comment: That's nice. What's the problem? Is there an error? If so, please put the full text in the body of your question.

Comment: @MattDMo nothing happens after entering command (have edited the question as it possible)

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a worksheet:

```
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
```

and then close the workbook:

```
workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

For completeness' sake, a short, but complete demo is shown in the docs: http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/example_demo.html#ex-demo

As Jkdc mentioned, you need to add a worksheet and close it in addition to "creating" it.